# How to recompile Haskell with cabal build showing only warnings

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I `cabal build` my projects, warnings (especially with `-Wall`) are only shown the first time.

On subsequent builds, everything is cached.

**I want to see all warnings of my project again.**

I could `cabal clean` and **recompile** or use `cabal build --ghc-options="-fforce-recomp"`, but that just **takes too long**.

How do I do a warning-check only **as fast as possible**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can speed up compilation by factor ~10 **skipping code generation**:

`cabal build --ghc-options="-fforce-recomp -fno-code"`

---

For only checking individual files, you can use [ghc-mod](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod): `ghc-mod check -g -Wall file.hs`.